# Control MIDI volume Java without synthesizer

Tags: java, midi

I have got the code below which should theoretically mute the sound (just to test if the volume control works) but it plays the sound at full volume as though the loop through the tracks is not there.

```
File music = new File(midi);
Sequencer sequencer;
Sequence sequence;
try {
    sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(music);
    sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
    sequencer.open();

    for (Track track : sequence.getTracks())
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 16; c++)
            track.add(new MidiEvent(
                new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.CONTROL_CHANGE, c, 7, 0),
                    track.ticks()));
    }

    sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
    sequencer.start();
} catch (MidiUnavailableException | IOException | InvalidMidiDataException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would anything change if you simply *add* the commands to a track? I bet they are added at the *end* of the tracks; so the control change does nothing. Try setting the tick parameter to 0, at least.

Also the tracks may already contain control changes on its own; altering volume as it needs. This approach is *not* how you control the volumne of the music. Its how you control selected tracks relative to each other.